# Configure dependencies in RPM

Tags: centos, rpm, haproxy

I have built a RPM-package for Centos 6.6 that is installed on a machine of our customer.
This package contains our own software, customized for the specific use case, but also uses the open-source package HAProxy.

HAProxy (RPM-version 1.5.4-2.el6_7.1) comes with a default-configuration in `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf` and it cannot be customized without changing this file.
But I want the configuration to be part my generated package. RPM throws an error if the `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf` file is in my package, because it is also part of the haproxy-package.

I have worked around this problem by providing a custom upstart-script which starts HAProxy with a different config file, but this does not seem to be the right way to do this.

Is there a preferred way to handle such customizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, I've created an RPM which installs configuration files into a different subdirectory, and in its `%post` and `%preun` scriptlets modifies the uncooperative package's config-files:

- when installing, I renamed the original config-files, and made symbolic links from those pathnames to the overwriting config-files, and
- when uninstalling, the package removed the symbolic links and restored the original package's files.

Doing it that way of course meant that my config-RPM was dependent on the original RPM.  A little awkward to describe, but it works.

In followup, the issue of *updating* was mentioned.  Updating an RPM requires special handling to avoid uninstalling things.  The `rpm` program passes a parameter `$1` which you can test in the `%pre` and `%preun` scriptlets to notice that this is an *upgrade* and that there is no need to save the original config-files (or restore them).  The rest of the scriptlet would be the same, by copying the new versions of your config-files over the others.

Further reading:

- [Defining installation scripts](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s04s05.html) (shows the use of `$1)
- [RPM upgrade uninstalls the RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398834/rpm-upgrade-uninstalls-the-rpm)

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511334/rpm-upgrade-handling-of-config-files) the modified config file might be overridden when doing `rpm -U`. Is your method preventing this behavior?

Comment: no - that's a different situation (it describes a case where `%config` *is used).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. On EL6 and sysv there is no other choice than creating custom haproxy package or custom haproxy service or create script which customer runs after installation. I see creating another service as best option.

Note that on EL7 with SystemD you have much better option as you can use Drop-In feature of SystemD. For more information see:

- https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Drop-in_snippets
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Service_example

Answer (score 0):

The usual way this is done is to have a drop-in configuration directory, e.g. `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, where your package would drop its configuration, and you would tell the other daemon, e.g. `httpd`, to do a graceful restart in your `%post`/`%postun`.

I don't know anything about HAProxy, but a quick search implies that they do not support this configuration directory concept that has been around for many years. A few people have hacked it in, but unless it is out-of-the-box, you will run into your original problem again.